# Cloudflare turnstile captcha not showing on login form

Tags: html, reactjs, cloudflare

I am currently developing a login page for a local React website and I am attempting to integrate Cloudflare turnstile, but I am encountering issues with it not appearing on the page. I followed the documentation and added the following lines of code to my code:

```
<script src="https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/api.js" async defer></script>
```

and

```
<div class="cf-turnstile" data-sitekey=“<YOUR_SITE_KEY>"></div>
```

However, the turnstile still does not show up. Below is the code I am currently working with:

```
<html lang="en">
              <head>
                  <title>Signup</title>
                  <script src="https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/api.js" async defer></script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div className="mobilelogo">
                    <img src={mobileLogo} alt=""/>
                    <span className="headingStyle"> News API</span>
                </div>

                <div className="parentClass">
                    <div className="mobilemode">

                        <div className="logostyle">
                            <img src={SignUpLogo} alt=""/>
                            <span className="headingStyle">News API</span>
                        </div>

                        <div className="divsection">
                            <span className="headingStyle" onClick={()=>setOpen(true)}>Create an account</span>
                            <span className="subheadingStyle">Sign up to continue </span>
                            <div className="inputBox">
                                <span className="labelHeading">Name</span>
                                <div >
                                        <TextField  inputProps={{ style: { marginLeft: '30px' } }}   value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} id="outlined-basic" label="Name" variant="outlined" />
                                        {nameError && <span className="error">{nameError}</span>}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="inputBox">
                                <span className="labelHeading">Email</span>
                                <div >
                                    <TextField inputProps={{ style: { marginLeft: '30px' } }} value={email}onChange={handleEmailChange} id="outlined-basic" label="Email" variant="outlined" />
                                    {emailError && <span className="error">{emailError}</span>}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="inputBox">
                                <span className="labelHeading">Password</span>
                                <div >
                                    <TextField inputProps={{ style: { marginLeft: '30px' } }} value={password} onChange={handlePasswordChange}  type="password"id="outlined-basic" label="Password" variant="outlined" />
                                    {passwordError && <span className="error">{passwordError}</span>}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                              <div className="cf-turnstile" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button className="buttonClass" onClick={()=> validationFunc()}><span className="buttonClassText">Create an account</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div  className="desktopMode">
                        <img src={RightCardImage} alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>

            <SnackbarFile open={open} setOpen={setOpen} msg ={globalmsg}/>
        </>
    )
}
```